# I am trying to build a peer to peer chat application in python but I am not getting the Idea to how to maintain chat history for each user?

Tags: python, database, client-server, chat, python-multithreading

I am trying to build a peer to peer chat application in python but I am not getting the Idea to how to maintain chat history for each user?
I have completed my code,here is some snippet but I am not getting the Idea of how to store and manage the chats happening between peer to another peer in this program...please help

```
import socket
import threading
import sys

class Server:
    connections = []
    peers = []
    def __init__(self):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 10001))
        sock.listen(1)

        while True:
            c,a = sock.accept()
            cThread = threading.Thread(target = self.handler, args=(c,a))
            cThread.daemon = True
            cThread.start()
            self.connections.append(c)
            self.peers.append(a[0])
            print(str(a[0]) + ':' + str(a[1]), "connected")
            self.sendPeers()




    def handler(c, a):
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            for connection in connections:
                connection.send(bytes(data))
            if not data:
                connections.remove(c)
                self.peers.remove(a[0])
                c.close()
                self.sendPeers()
                break

    def sendPeers(self):
        p=""
        for peer in peers:
            p = p + peer + ","

        for connection in self.connections:
            connection.send(b'\x11' + bytes(p, "utf-8"))


class Client:
    def sendMsg(self, sock):
        while True:
            sock.send(bytes(input(""), 'utf-8'))

    def __init__(self, address):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect((address, 10000))

        iThread = threading.Thread(target = self.sendMsg, args=(sock,))
        iThread.daemon = True
        iThread.start()

        while True:
            data = sock.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            if data[0:1] == b'\x11':
                print("got peers")
            print(str(data, 'utf-8'))


if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
    client = Client(sys.argv[1])
else:
    server = Server()
```

Comment: for saving and maintaining chat history...I am thinking to do same mysql....but I am not getting the clear vision...please help

Comment: Unfortunately, stack overflow is geared towards specific questions and answers, and this is a question that's too broad for the site. However, I will say that you could start by thinking about doing this simply in-python, and eventually integrate a database later.

Comment: You might start by defining what it is you want to keep in the history record.  For example, this might be the names of the sender and receiver, the date/time sent, and the message text.  These could be attributes of a Python class, and you could preserve the data either by pickling it or by creating a database table with columns to represent these values and writing an interface to read/write class objects from/to the database.